# Xcode 14 navigation bar whited out with UIHostingController

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have noticed a bug introduced when building with Xcode 14.
The navigation bar of my swiftui view is whited out and does not properly display the title, back button or other navigation items.
I haven't found anyone else reporting this issue online but it is clearly a change in how Xcode builds the app.

I have verified that building with Xcode 13.4.1 produces the expected navigation bar.

I manually downloaded 13.4.1 in order to continue deploying builds without this bug but I know eventually I will have to investigate why Xcode 14 is causing this issue. I'm hoping there is a fix that Apple discovers and releases to fix this issue.

The navigation bar is programmatically set through a view controller using a UIHostingController as its rootView.

I have found that this only happens when injecting swiftui into a UIKit app using UIHostingController. The SwiftUI view does not use a NavigationView so there shouldn't be any overlap between what is displayed in the navigation bar from the viewController and what is displayed from the SwiftUI view.

Comment: If you have a bug, you should submit it to Apple. There doesn't seem to be a question here for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Submitted to apple, will update this post if/when I get an answer back.

Comment: Hi, any updates? I'm facing the same issue, and I would appreciate any help with it.

Comment: I sent a support request but have not heard back from Apple yet.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully, they reply soon, and if they do, please add the answer here, Thanks,

Comment: I opened spa. question in developer forums about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718260)

Comment: Still no word from apple, this is still an issue in Xcode 14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard back from Apple but I figured out the issue!

In my case the app had a few settings that worked in Xcode 13 but created the issue in Xcode 14.

1. I had to remove this key/val from the Info.plist for my app
   UIStatusBarStyle
   UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent
2. I removed a setting that was set in AppDelegate

```
  application.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyleLightContent)
```

3. I explicitly called this in every ViewController (I used a base class that all my View Controllers inherit)

```
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated:false)
```

After the above changes the navigation bar showed up correctly and the top status bar also displayed correctly.